# WiX project is never up-to-date

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

I have an installer (.msi) project that uses Wix Toolset v3.14. For some reason it is never up-to-date -- i.e. building it again always produces some activity (`C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.14\bin\Light.exe` gets called, but not `candle.exe`). Is there any way to track down and fix the cause?

Here is what I observe when detailed output is ON:

```
Target "ReadPreviousBindInputsAndBuiltOutputs" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\wix.targets" from project "<my-project>" (target "Link" depends on it):
    Task "ReadLinesFromFile"
        Task Parameter:File=obj\x64\Debug\<my-project>.wixproj.BindContentsFileListen-us.txt
        Output Item(s): 
    _BindInputs=
        C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Temp\a5uljxg1\MergeId.418703\api_ms_win_core_console_l1_1_0.dll.AF4EABEE_4589_3789_BA0A_C83A71662E1D
        ...
Done building target "ReadPreviousBindInputsAndBuiltOutputs" in project "<my-project>.wixproj".
Target "Link" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\wix.targets" from project "<my-project>.wixproj" (target "CompileAndLink" depends on it):
    Building target "Link" completely.
    Input file "C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Temp\a5uljxg1\MergeId.418703\api_ms_win_core_console_l1_1_0.dll.AF4EABEE_4589_3789_BA0A_C83A71662E1D" does not exist.
    ...
    <and here it executes Light.exe>
```

So, it looks like it reads `BindContentsFileListen-us.txt` and expects it to contain files that were inputs during last build run. But, unfortunately some of these files were generated in temporary folder and got wiped out (presumably during last build) and since they don't exist anymore -- `Link` step is re-executed. I observe this pattern every time I press F7, only number in `MergeId.418703` gets changed every time (looks like process id to me).

**UPDATE**: this is a known (and pretty old) [issue](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4048). As of now it is planned to be fixed in WiX v4.0.

Comment: If you turn the build log up to diagnostic log level (Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity) it usually has the reason why it's building a project as the first log line when you build the solution. Make sure if you're generating any files at all you use appropriate inputs/outputs attributes on your msbuild targets.

Comment: @BrianSutherland I've updated my question with additional observations...

Comment: Yeah MSBuild will run a target if the outputs don't exist, an input doesnt exist, or any input modified date is newer than any output modified date. It looks like you are missing that temp file so it will rebuild. Unfortunately I don't know where it's coming from or why it gets deleted every run. You'd probably have to delve into the wix.targets or slowly read through the msbuild output to figure it out. When I build a installer project again I just get `Skipping target "Link" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.`

Comment: I bet this is because my `.wxs` merges in `Microsoft_VC140_CRT_x64.msm`... Alas, my WiX knowledge is very basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have hit the same issue, and the only information I found apart from this question was a pretty unhelpful mail thread from 2013 ([1](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Project-with-merge-modules-defeating-incremental-build-facility-td7584279.html), [2](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Re-Project-with-merge-modules-defeating-incremental-build-facility-td7584323.html#none)) and an [issue](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4048) from the same era.

## Troubleshooting

Reading through the logs and Wix's source code shows that the bugs occurs as follows:

- `light.exe`, the linker, receives all of the object (`.wixobj`) files it should combine, some of them referencing the `.msm` merge module's file path.
- `light.exe` uses a combination of [`mergemod.dll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/merge-module-automation)'s [`IMsmMerge::ExtractCAB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mergemod/nf-mergemod-imsmmerge-extractcab) and `cabinet.dll`'s [`::FDICopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fdi/nf-fdi-fdicopy) (through their own `winterop.dll`) to extract the contents of the merge module to a temporary path:

  ```cs
  // Binder.cs:5612, ProcessMergeModules

  // extract the module cabinet, then explode all of the files to a temp directory
  string moduleCabPath = String.Concat(this.TempFilesLocation, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, safeMergeId, ".module.cab");
  merge.ExtractCAB(moduleCabPath);

  string mergeIdPath = String.Concat(this.TempFilesLocation, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, "MergeId.", safeMergeId);
  Directory.CreateDirectory(mergeIdPath);

  using (WixExtractCab extractCab = new WixExtractCab())
  {
      try
      {
          extractCab.Extract(moduleCabPath, mergeIdPath);
      }
      // [...]
  }
  ```
- At the same time, the contents of the merge module are inserted among the other input files in the `fileRows` collection:

  ```cs
  // Binder.cs:5517, ProcessMergeModules

  // NOTE: this is very tricky - the merge module file rows are not added to the
  // file table because they should not be created via idt import.  Instead, these
  // rows are created by merging in the actual modules
  FileRow fileRow = new FileRow(null, this.core.TableDefinitions["File"]);
  // [...]
  fileRow.Source = String.Concat(this.TempFilesLocation, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, "MergeId.", wixMergeRow.Number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat), Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, record[1]);

  FileRow collidingFileRow = fileRows[fileRow.File];
  FileRow collidingModuleFileRow = (FileRow)uniqueModuleFileIdentifiers[fileRow.File];

  if (null == collidingFileRow && null == collidingModuleFileRow)
  {
      fileRows.Add(fileRow);

      // keep track of file identifiers in this merge module
      uniqueModuleFileIdentifiers.Add(fileRow.File, fileRow);
  }
  // [...]
  ```
- `fileRows` ends up being written to the `<project_name>BindContentsFileList<culture>.txt` file inside the intermediate directory, including the temporary (and randomly named) files extracted from the merge module:

  ```cs
  // Binder.cs:7346

  private void CreateContentsFile(string path, FileRowCollection fileRows)
  {
      string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
      if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
      {
          Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
      }

      using (StreamWriter contents = new StreamWriter(path, false))
      {
          foreach (FileRow fileRow in fileRows)
          {
              contents.WriteLine(fileRow.Source);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- During the next build, the `ReadPreviousBindInputsAndBuiltOutputs` target from `wix2010.targets` reads the file into the `@(_BindInputs)` item group. This item group is then listed as input to the `Link` target. Since the temporary files have since disappeared, the target is always considered out-of-date and re-run, generating an new set of temporary files that get listed in `BindContentsFileList`, and so on.

## Workaround

An actual fix would be to patch Wix so that merge modules discoverd in `.wixobj` files are listed in `BindContentsFileList`, and files extracted from them during linking aren't. Unfortunately I wasn't able to make Wix's source code compile, and can't be bothered to go through its distribution process. Hence, here is the workaround I have implemented.

### Removing temporary files from the input list

This is done using a custom target which slots in-between `ReadPreviousBindInputsAndBuiltOutputs` and `Link` and filters `@(_BindInputs)` to remove whatever is under `%temp%`.

```xml
<Target
    Name="RemoveTempFilesFromBindInputs"
    DependsOnTargets="ReadPreviousBindInputsAndBuiltOutputs"
    BeforeTargets="Link"
>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- This includes a final backslash, so we can use StartsWith. -->
        <TemporaryDirectory>$([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath())</TemporaryDirectory>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <_BindInputs
            Remove="@(_BindInputs)"
            Condition="$([System.String]::new('%(FullPath)').StartsWith('$(TemporaryDirectory)'))"
        />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

At that point, `Link` triggers only when actual input files change. Success! However, changes to the `.msm` files are not detected. This might be good enough a solution anyway, since merge modules are generally static. Otherwise...

### Detecting changes to merge modules

The main hurdle is that the only reference to the `.msm` file is within a `.wxs` source file, so we need to bridge the gap between that and MSBuild. There are a couple ways that can be used, such as parsing the `.wixobj` to fish out the `WixMerge` tables. However, I already had code in place to *generate* Wix code, so I went that way, lifting the merge modules into an MSBuild item group and using a custom task to generate a `.wxs` file referencing them in a feature. Full code below:

```xml
<Target
    Name="GenerateMsmFragment"
    BeforeTargets="GenerateCompileWithObjectPath"
    Inputs="@(MsmFiles)"
    Outputs="$(IntermediateOutputPath)MsmFiles.wxs"
>
    <GenerateMsmFragment
        MsmFiles="@(MsmFiles)"
        FeatureName="MsmFiles"
        MediaId="2"
        OutputFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)MsmFiles.wxs"
    >
        <Output TaskParameter="OutputFile" ItemName="Compile" />
    </GenerateMsmFragment>
</Target>
```

```cs
// GenerateMsmFragment.cs

using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;

namespace tasks
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public class GenerateMsmFragment : Task
    {
        [Required]
        public ITaskItem[] MsmFiles { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FeatureName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MediaId { get; set; }

        [Output]
        public ITaskItem OutputFile { get; set; }

        public override bool Execute()
        {
            var xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi";

            var outputXml = new XmlDocument();
            outputXml.AppendChild(outputXml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));

            var fragmentElem = outputXml
                .AppendElement("Wix", xmlns)
                .AppendElement("Fragment", xmlns);

            {
                var mediaElem = fragmentElem.AppendElement("Media", xmlns);
                mediaElem.SetAttribute("Id", MediaId);
                mediaElem.SetAttribute("Cabinet", "MsmFiles.cab");
                mediaElem.SetAttribute("EmbedCab", "yes");
            }

            {
                var directoryRefElem = fragmentElem.AppendElement("DirectoryRef", xmlns);
                directoryRefElem.SetAttribute("Id", "TARGETDIR");

                var featureElem = fragmentElem.AppendElement("Feature", xmlns);
                featureElem.SetAttribute("Id", FeatureName);
                featureElem.SetAttribute("Title", "Imported MSM files");
                featureElem.SetAttribute("AllowAdvertise", "no");
                featureElem.SetAttribute("Display", "hidden");
                featureElem.SetAttribute("Level", "1");

                foreach (var msmFilePath in MsmFiles.Select(i => i.ItemSpec)) {
                    var mergeElem = directoryRefElem.AppendElement("Merge", xmlns);
                    mergeElem.SetAttribute("Id", msmFilePath);
                    mergeElem.SetAttribute("SourceFile", msmFilePath);
                    mergeElem.SetAttribute("DiskId", MediaId);
                    mergeElem.SetAttribute("Language", "0");

                    featureElem
                        .AppendElement("MergeRef", xmlns)
                        .SetAttribute("Id", msmFilePath);
                }
            }

            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(OutputFile.GetMetadata("FullPath")));
            outputXml.Save(OutputFile.GetMetadata("FullPath"));

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
// XmlExt.cs

using System.Xml;

namespace nrm
{
    public static class XmlExt
    {
        public static XmlElement AppendElement(this XmlDocument element, string qualifiedName, string namespaceURI)
        {
            var newElement = element.CreateElement(qualifiedName, namespaceURI);
            element.AppendChild(newElement);
            return newElement;
        }

        public static XmlElement AppendElement(this XmlNode element, string qualifiedName, string namespaceURI)
        {
            var newElement = element.OwnerDocument.CreateElement(qualifiedName, namespaceURI);
            element.AppendChild(newElement);
            return newElement;
        }
    }
}
```

And voilà, working up-to-date detection for merge modules.

Comment: That's a nice writeup! I'll check if it works for me and will get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: It works, though I must point out that with workaround build still gets executed (i.e. it is not up-to-date), but it skips `light.exe` steps (because we modify inputs list as part of the build). Thank you, @Quentin.

Comment: @C.M. I've been playing around with a trivial Wix project, and it looks like the Wix VS extension does not *have* a fast up-to-date check at all. Searching through the source code has not yielded anything, so I'm inclined to think that's the best we're going to get.